# How to edit Google spreadsheets in Kinetise's mobile application?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I develop app in kinetise tool and I found it is possible to easly add list with Google spreadsheet content. But I don't know whether it is possible to edit sheets from user account (when it is public or user sign up with Google). Let's say add records for specific position (A1) in specific sheet (SheetName). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can both view your spreadsheet (read) and edit it (write) in Kinetise.

Firstly, publish your sheet and get public URL address (File -> Publish to web).
Now in Kinetise editor add List widget and select "From Google Sheets" in Online source view. Paste your URL address and data from sheet should be displayed.

What about write, well you need to Sign-In with Google first. So please add Google login method to your application. You can do this attaching Google login widget to your Splash Screen. 
Then in screen where you want to edit sheet please add Form widget. Select "To RESTful API" as form send destination. Paste below url:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}:append?insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&access_token=##GetGoogleUserAccessToken##
```

where

{spreadsheetId} - yours spreadsheet ID (same as in List widget's URL);

{range} - columns range: A1:B1 (depends on number of columns in your table).

The last thing you have to do is to edit send request body. Please click Settings button on the right of URL address. In Body tab and Request body transform section please paste:

```
{  "values": [
        [ .form.field1, .form.field2 ]    
    ]  
}
```

field1 and field2 are names of form fields, so if you have another names or more columns please change it. And that's all, now you should be able to edit spreadsheet.